# Change image property using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have particular css through which I am hiding image. Now I want to develop jquery through which if particular field is blank on blur than image of class error should be shown..

```
.error{
display:none;
}


<tr>
    <th width="30%">Email:</th>
    <td width="63%"><input type="text" name="email" id="email" title="Email*" class="validate"/></td>
    <td width="05%"><img width="27" height="27" id="erroremail" src="images/error.png" alt="Error" title="N/A*" class="error"></td>
</tr>..
```

And I develop jquery for this is

```
$('.validate').blur(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == '') {

        $(this).next('.error').show().css({'display':'block'});
                alert("null");

    } else {

        $(this).next('.error').hide();
        alert("not null");
        }
});
```

Though I am not getting any error on console. Even alert is also running but jquery is not working.

Comment: Are you binding the blur event in the jQuery ready event (i.e. after the DOM is loaded)?

Comment: of course...I have done that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`next()` returns the immediately following sibling.

In your case there are no siblings for the .validate element, instead the elamenet you want to target is in the next table cell .

You have to use `$('.error', $(this).parent().next())` to get hold of the `.error` element.

1) `$(this).parent()` -- return the parent `td` element.
2) `next()` returns the next `td` cell.
3) `$(".validate", $(this).parent().next())` returns all the elements with validate class which are children of `$(this).parent().next()`.

```
$('.validate').blur(function() {     
    if ($(this).val() == '') {          
        $('.error', $(this).parent().next()).show();
        alert("null");      
    } else {          
        $('.error', $(this).parent().next()).hide();
        alert("not null");         
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't find right element. Try this:

```
$('.validate').blur(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == '') {

        $(this).closest('tr').find('.error').show();
                alert("null");

    } else {

        $(this).closest('tr').find('.error').hide();
        alert("not null");
        }
});
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/6dWFs/

Answer (score 2):

`next()` points to nothing, because you're in a table. First select the parent cell, then select the `.error` element:

```
$(this).parents('td:first').next().find('.error')
```

Final code:

```
$('.validate').blur(function() {
    var errorImg = $(this).parents('td:first').next().find('.error');
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
        errorImg.show().css({'display':'block'});
                alert("null");
    } else {
        errorImg.hide();
        alert("not null");
    }
});
```